# Trazer registro sql mesmo não tendo o acento necessário

Tags: php, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Preciso trazer um registro chamado `Vidraçaria` em uma pesquisa, como posso trazer este registro escrevendo apenas **Vidracaria** na pesquisa?

> Ou trazer **água** buscando apenas `agua`

A pesquisa funciona normal quando a palavra é escrita corretamente, com ou sem acento.

Estou usando like() para buscar as informações nos registros mysql

Comment: Já vi essa pergunta e não consegui ter nenhum resultado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use uma função para retirar os acentos da palavra buscada e do que está no banco. Desta forma irá encontrar a palavra com ou sem acentos:

```
function tiraacentos($i){
   return preg_replace(array("/(á|à|ã|â|ä|Á|À|Ã|Â|Ä)/","/(é|è|ê|ë|É|È|Ê|Ë)/","/(í|ì|î|ï|Í|Ì|Î|Ï)/","/(ó|ò|õ|ô|ö|Ó|Ò|Õ|Ô|Ö)/","/(ú|ù|û|ü|Ú|Ù|Û|Ü)/","/(ñ|Ñ)/","/(ç|Ç)/","/(ý|ÿ|Ý)/"),explode(" ","a e i o u n c y"),$i);
}
```

Na query você usa a função no nome da tabela do BD e no termo buscado:

```
$palavra = $_POST['palavra'];
"SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE ".tiraacentos(NOME DA TABELA)." LIKE '%".tiraacentos($palavra)."%'"
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar um `collation` diferente em tempo de execução para remover os acentos:

```
...
WHERE nome like '%vidracaria%' collate utf8_general_ci
```

Ou para o caso do erro apontado:

```
...
WHERE nome like '%vidracaria%' collate utf8mb4_general_ci
```

Comment: Traz a seguinte mensagem do HeidiSQL "Collation 'utf8_general_ci' is not valid for character set 'utf8mb4'"

Comment: @R.Wegner Tente o mesmo comando acima mas troque utf8_general_ci por utf8mb4

Comment: Não retornou nenhum erro, mas também não retornou nada